# Rewrite Rule with dynamic hostname

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm interesting in rewrite rule to modify some url and paths. Here some Examples.
I have some hostnames which lookups to 1 VirtualHost throught ServerAlias in Apache conf.

example.com
anotherdomain.com
same.org

And a lot of anothers domains. Here, what I want to do:

```
example.com/uploads/photo.png -> /www/example.com/uploads/example.com/photo.png<br />

anotherdomain.com/uploads/photo.png -> /www/anotherdomain.com/uploads/anotherdomain.com/photo.png<br />
```

And same thing with another domains. This thing I've made already.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^uploads/([a-zA-Z0-9-\._]+)$ uploads/%2/$1 [L]
```

This work perfectly. But, if I try to access uploads/icons/category/image.png 
I start to see 500 Internal Apache Error...
I've modify Rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads/%{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^uploads/([a-zA-Z0-9-\._/]+)$ uploads/%2/$1 [L]
```

And Enable Apache Rewrite log with 9 verbosity.

```
RewriteCond: input='/uploads/icons/category/image.png' pattern='!^/uploads/%{HTTP_HOST}' => matched
rewrite 'uploads/icons/category/image.png' -> 'uploads/example.com/icons/category/image.png'
RewriteCond: input='/uploads/example.com/icons/category/image.png' pattern='!^/uploads/%{HTTP_HOST}' => matched
rewrite 'uploads/example.com/icons/category/image.png' -> 'uploads/example.com/example.com/icons/category/image.png'
```

And after that, it's exhausts 10 lookups =(

When I modify to this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads/example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^uploads/([a-zA-Z0-9-\._/]+)$ uploads/%2/$1 [L]
```

It's works perfectle for ALL stuff, but only for 1 domain: example.com

I found another solution, but it's not a perfect.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^uploads/([a-zA-Z0-9-\._/]+)$ uploads/%2/$1 [L]
```

This Rule works only if I have existed dir and file. But, if i try to access:
`/uploads/images/not-existed-404.nothing` -> It return 500, because this file doesn't exists and rewriting into:

```
/uploads/example.com/example.com/example.com/example.com.......
```

*P.S. Sorry for my bad English ;)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads/%{HTTP_HOST}
```

You CANNOT use variables or back references in pattern -- i.e. `%{HTTP_HOST}` will not be expanded to `example.com`, instead it will be treated as normal text.

---

You can uses these rules (working fine on my PC):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/uploads/%2/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.+)$ uploads/%2/$1 [L]
```

1. This rule will check if target file does exist and only then rewrites (order of conditions matter).
2. Let's assume:

   - domain name: `example.com`
   - website root: `/www/example.com/`
   - URL requested: `/uploads/img/meow.png`

   Second condition (`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/uploads/%2/$1 -f`) will check if file `/www/example.com/uploads/example.com/img/meow.png` exists, and if it does -- then rewrite occurs.

Your .htaccess then may look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# do not do anything for already existing files & folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# rewrite uploads to domain-specific folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/uploads/%2/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.+)$ uploads/%2/$1 [L]
```